# Blazor template with menu across the top

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I've created a new blazor app from the VS2019 template which has the menu as a sidebar. I've spent best part of the morning trying to get the menu across the top of the page like the current MVC template but completely failed to get anywhere!

Does anyone have a blazor template with the navbar remove from the side and across the top?

Comment: Blazor use HTML and CSS. The menu is little different than the one use eg by the Angular (or any SPA) template, on purpose. The horizontal menu comes from *Bootstrap* , it's not something specific to MVC - it's just a [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/). If I remember correctly, Blazor uses bootstrap too.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The sidebar in Blazor isn't something special. If you check `MainLayout.razor` you'll see  a reference to a NavMenu component with the `sidebar` class :

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
```

If you open `NavMenu.razor` you'll see it's just a [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/), conveniently packed in a reusable component.

**Update**

Blazor uses Bootstrap which makes the rest of the problem a stylesheet problem, not a Blazor issue.

[image: Small Screen]

The Blazor template's stylesheet was built for this specific Explorer-like layout - a vertical navbar on the left, the main area on the right. The colors, sizes and most importantly, flow, are designed for this. It's not enough to modify a single style class.

On the other hand, the **Razor pages** stylesheet was built for the "classic" Bootstrap look with the menu on top, containers and rows in the middle, footers and headers. This means, we can "borrow" the stylesheet and layout from a new Razor Pages application.

1. Create a new project with `dotnet new webapp`
2. Remove everything in Blazor's `site.css` except the first line :

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');
```

3. Copy the contents of Razor's `site.css` to Blazor's `site.css`. The file should look like this :

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');

a.navbar-brand {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
...
```

4. Modify Blazor's `Shared\MainLayout.razor` to mimic the structure in Razor's `Shared\_Layout.cshtml` :

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase


<header>
  <NavMenu />
</header>

<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @Body
    </main>
</div>
```

No footer here since there's no `Privacy` page in the Blazor template.

5. Modify `Shared\NavMenu.razor` to use the structure and styles of the Razor template. `<a>` elements need to be replaged by `NavLink` elements. The other tricky part is that the toggler in Razor works through the `data-toggle="collapse" data-target` attributes which don't work in Blazor. That's why the click handler is needed :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">blazornav</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="@NavMenuCssClass"  @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>                
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The click handler simply adds or removes the `collapse` class to the base navbar style copied from Razor

```
@code {
    bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    string baseMenuClass = "navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse";

    string NavMenuCssClass => baseMenuClass + (collapseNavMenu ? " collapse" : "");

    void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

This results in a horizontal menu with a toggler on the right:

[image: Large Screen]

Comment: This is true, however trying to get the sidebar across the top has proved impossible so far

Comment: Also, its not just a case of "dropping" a bootstrap 4 nav in as the current template supplied is integrated with razor components.

Comment: @Calanus it's nothing more than that. The current NavBar is just that - a Bootstrap Navbar. The code simply changes the class of the navbar so it collapes or expands.

Comment: @Calanus the *real* problem is the style and layout of the entire site. Even if you remove all classes from the navbar inside NavMenu, the layout is affected by the `main` and `toprows` style classes of the *main* content. The layout specified in `site.css` is made for a vertical navbar with the rest used for content. You should start with a new stylesheet appropriate for *your* site. Just for experimenting, you could just clear the `site.css` file or copy an existing stylesheet

Comment: Have tried again, dropping in an MVC navbar and replacing the css. Made progress but none of the links are clickable. There is something else going on in blazor that is affecting it.

Comment: if you can provide a working top navbar template you can win the bounty.

Comment: @Calanus I did by copying the style and layout from a new Razor Pages project.

Comment: "Remove everything in Blazor's site.css except the first line :" I cannot stress this enough, DO NOT remove everything in the main.css, you MUST keep the "#blazor-error-ui" and "#blazor-error-ui .dismiss" css rules.  If you do not keep these, then while you are developing your app, you will not see a notification of any exceptions when they occur.  This is not so bad if using server side blazor, as the VS debugger will normally break, but in the WASM model, you will not see exceptions in the browser code unless the error ui styles are maintained.

Comment: @shawty this was a Blazor *server* question about CSS formatting, posted when even Blazor Server was a very early preview. I don't even remember whether there was anything called `#blazor-error-ui` back then.

Comment: @shawty as for the question and answer themselves, it was about persuading the OP that Blazor styling is just styling, and producing the full CSS and code because nothing else was enough to convince. The comments go on for 4 days, until I finally had to write everything to prove the point

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The styles have been there in SSB ever since the 3rd preview pre core 3.1, and while I appreciate that the question was written back then, it's almost certainly going to get seen by more up to date searches, searches against SSB & CSB versions that do have that styling in, and that with the removal of that styling, will cause even more confusion for new comers to using blazor.  As for persuading, yes I get that, not saying you did a bad job (Which you appear to think I am) all I'm saying is, DON'T remove the error-ui styles, otherwise you'll get more problems.

Comment: If these "#blazor-error-ui" and "#blazor-error-ui .dismiss" are removed, a creepy message remains at the bottom saying that some error has occurred - Reload. Otherwise this tweaking appears awesome!

Comment: hello, is there a way to horizontally put navmenu to bottom ?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just went through the same thing yesterday. Very frustrating. I was able to get rid of the sidebar and put the menu on top. Unfortunately, after I did that, in small devices, when the menu is expanded after clicking the toggle button, the brand, toggle button and menu were all vertically centered on the expanded area, where one expects only the menu items to appear. The brand and the toggle button should remain on the top row.

[Expanded menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SlUu.png)

This morning, I came across a post (https://www.nativoplus.studio/blog/blazor-layouts/) that suggests the bootstrap css included in the Blazor template is modified. To get the default behavior, you need to comment it (and the site.css) out of _Host.cshtml and replace it with the official bootstrap css file.

When I did that, the menu began working almost correctly. The weird format went away. My problem now is that on small devices, after making a menu selection, the menu does not collapse. I'm assuming it has to do with the way Blazor handles UI changes. In other words, since the menu content didn't change after making the selection, it doesn't re-render the menu.

If I come up w a way to collapse the menu, I'll post it here.

Comment: I'm glad its not just me! I think you might be able to collapse the menu using the razor code in the standard template - I'll check it out over the weekend

Answer (score 0):

You can remove most of the content in the MainLayout.razor leaving just the essentials, and create your own css stylings in the razor page using the style tags.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>Portfolio</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <main>
        @Body
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to denigrate anybody else's efforts here. I've edited that out. Afterall we're all volunteers, and this is a free site. If you have any criticisms of anybody's posts here (content length and readability are certainly valid as such), you're welcome to post a polite comment on how they can improve them, once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other commenters here it seems the default template has modified bootstrap included.

If you are starting a new project upgrade to .NET 7 and you can make use of the blank Blazor template.