# Positioning of Menu navbars created using VS2019 Blazor App and ASP.NET Core Web Application templates

Tags: css, razor, bootstrap-4, blazor

Having read the question [Blazor template with menu across the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235005/blazor-template-with-menu-across-the-top/58235593#58235593) and noting that it seems non trivial to move the navbar from the LHS to the top of the page and vice versa I am left wondering if there is any existing or emergent technical reason that gives preference to positioning the Menu at either the Top or the LHS of the page.

I understand from the referenced discussion that the root cause of the difference is that the Blazor template uses a modified form of the site.css file that is used by the ASP.NET Core Web Application template.

Since I'm about to do some development using Blazor I'd be grateful if anyone can tell me any technical or other reasons for not adopting the Blazor Application template's modified site.css file.

Comment: It's just a layout. The designer who made the template first chose to use LHS navigation for the SPA, and left the top navigation for authentication template stuff. Nothing stops you from doing your own layout and placing a menu wherever you want, you'll just have to rewrite the one MS provide.

Comment: Thanks rdmptn.  Sounds like an answer to me.