# Top Menu instead of side menu in Blazor from WebAssembly template in VS2019

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have read and studied a similar question [Blazor template with menu across the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235005/blazor-template-with-menu-across-the-top), however I am still not understanding why a simple top menu is not easier using the Blazor template in Visual Studio.
I use this simple code in MainLayout.razor to test what the container will look like when i run the code:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <!--<NavMenu />-->
    </nav>
</div>
```

I have even commented out NavMenu.razor, but still the navbar does not stretch all the way across the page.

[image]

Looks like the Blazor Template still does not support top navigation menu's by default ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that your component `NavMenu` is commented out, please uncomment and see if it works, code should be like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <NavMenu />
    </nav>
</div>
```

If that's not the case, then follow below:

So this is not something related to Blazor, but HTML/CSS and as you are using Bootstrap you can get help from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

Basically, you might need to change the HTML that is in the `NavMenu` component to match the HTML from the above bootstrap link, you can use any sample code from there, for example, this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#nav

Comment: Actually that is why I commented it out -- it had no affect on the NavMenu.razor width not expanding across the page. It seems the code contained in app.css must be modified from the template in order to make this work as _"The Blazor template's stylesheet was built for this specific Explorer-like layout"_ . I was hoping for an easier solution but so far have not found anything.

Comment: Agree with you, you will have to change some HTML and css, and that is "the" way to make this change whether easy or not.