# Bootstrap nav items not rendering correct in Blazor client project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor

The bootstrap nav items in code are not aligning properly in Blazor client side project. I am using the techniques described in [Blazor template with menu across the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235005/blazor-template-with-menu-across-the-top)  but am still having this problem. Here is NavMenu.razor:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark
     border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Top Menu</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="@NavMenuCssClass navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" @onclick="CollapseNavMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" href="counter">Counter</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" href="fetchdata">Fetch data</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<header>
    <NavMenu />
</header>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        @Body
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried to modify the site.css file for nav-item, and have tried deleting all definitions for them as well but still getting this behavior:

[image: Nav-Items]

Comment: Correction -- This is a blazor server side app -- not wasm

Answer (score 1):

After much research, I was able to fix this problem by commenting out the .css link tag found in `_Host.cshtml`. The .css file to comment out is `<link href="[Nameofproject].styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`